# Correct syntax for multiple modules in vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, store, vuex-modules

Vue and vuex begginer. I am trying to set a single store with multiple modules in vuex.

The folder structure is

```
store (folder)
  index.js
  modules (folder)
    hoodies.js
    shoes.js
```

My `index.js` has

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import hoodies from'./modules/hoodies';
import shoes from'./modules/shoes';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        hoodies
        ,shoes
    }
})
```

Inside `hoodies.js` and `shoes.js` I have the same structure, the difference is the word "shoes" or "hoodies"

```
import axios from 'axios'

const state = {    
    shoes:[]
};

const getters = {
    allShoes : state => state.shoes    
};

const actions = { 
    async fetchShoes({commit}){ //.... 
}

const mutations = {
    setShoes:(state, shoes) => (state.shoes = shoes),
}

export default{
    namespaced: true,    
    state,
    getters,
    actions, 
    mutations
};
```

I want to use shoes and hoodies in the same component. I am confused because I dont know if this is the correct syntax and a lot of tutorials do not explain how to do this.

So, I am trying like so.

```
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'; 

methods:{
          ...mapActions('./store/modules/shoes', [ 'fetchShoes' ]),
          ...mapActions('./store/modules/hoodies', [ 'fetchHoodies' ]), 
          comboboxChange(){
            this.fetchHoodies();
          }
},
created(){
  this.fetchShoes(); 
}
```

I get no errors in the console. But the browser console says `[vuex] module namespace not found in mapActions(): ./store/modules/shoes/`

Please help me debug this, a simple solution goes a long way. I dont know what to do. Thanks

Comment: Right now your imports make no sense, you're importing `vessels`, but still shorthanding `hoodies`. Show your actual code, as it is, this wouldn't build and would throw a number of errors.

Answer (score 3):

First problem I see is that you import your modules as "vessels" and "charts", so you need to register that names in module. I recommend to change your imports like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import hoodies from'./modules/hoodies';
import shoes from'./modules/shoes';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        hoodies,
        shoes
    }
})
```

You don't need getters to return exact state values, you can reach state directly from component. Since you are using namespaced modules you get state value in component like this: `this.$store.state.shoes.shoes`

Getters you usually use when you need some computed value(s) from state.